# How TCP window size is impacted on setting SO_RCVBUF (using setsockopt) after three way handshake?

Tags: sockets, unix, tcp

I accept a TCP connection with default values and I observe SYN, ACK being sent with a window size of 64K and a window scale factor of 7.

After 3 way handshake is complete and exchanging some control packets for my app, I use setsockopt() to set SO_RCVBUF to 20K. My question is when the advertised window will get updated in this case?
As the sb_hiwat has been modified to a smaller value, shouldn't I see a window update packet right away? What I am seeing is a gradual decrease in advertised window which takes ~4 seconds to reach from ~7MB to 20K.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would ever want to reduce the receive buffer at all.

You may not even be able to once transmissions have started, but in any case if there is data in the receive buffer you certainly can't expect it to get set to less than that immediately. Otherwise data would have to be discarded, and TCP doesn't allow that.

I suggest you leave it alone.

Comment: EPJ, I agree that it is not a good idea to reduce the receive buffer but I am dealing with a legacy design and leaving it alone is not an option. I'm looking at the kernel code and all setsockopt() does is change the sb_hiwat. I will need to dig more in the tcp code to find out why window is not getting shrink right away after  the sb_hiwat has been changed. BTW, I am working on FreeBsd stack.

Comment: Why? Why would a legacy peer care what the TCP window size was? Why can't you set to what you want before the accept or connect and not have to change it at all? I don't understand any of this.

Comment: The partial answer to WHY is statistics. The server side always accepts the connection on a default larger window, though the client set the option before it does a connect. Once the threeway handshake is complete and after a few session level messages are exchanged, client side sends a session layer packet to set the window size on the server for the session.

Comment: Just realized I typed EPJ instead of EJP while addressing you, sorry about that.